# How to import PIxi.js in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, pixi.js

I have a simple app just for testing Meteor and Pixi.js.

My main.jsx (the only script file):

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import PIXI from 'pixi.js';



Meteor.startup(()=>{
  render(
    <p>zdzdzd</p>,
    document.getElementById('container')
  );
});
```

But have an error when importing PIXI

```
graceful-fs.js:157 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
patch   @   graceful-fs.js:157
meteorInstall.node_modules.graceful-fs.graceful-fs.js   @   graceful-fs.js:27
fileEvaluate    @   install.js:153
require @   install.js:82
meteorInstall.node_modules.glslify-deps.index.js    @   index.js:2
fileEvaluate    @   install.js:153
require @   install.js:82
meteorInstall.node_modules.glslify.index.js @   index.js:3
fileEvaluate    @   install.js:153
require @   install.js:82
meteorInstall.node_modules.pixi.js.src.core.renderers.webgl.filters.spriteMask.SpriteMaskFilter.js  @   SpriteMaskFilter.js:5
fileEvaluate    @   install.js:153
require @   install.js:82
meteorInstall.node_modules.pixi.js.src.core.renderers.webgl.managers.MaskManager.js @   MaskManager.js:2
fileEvaluate    @   install.js:153
require @   install.js:82
meteorInstall.node_modules.pixi.js.src.core.renderers.webgl.WebGLRenderer.js    @   WebGLRenderer.js:2
fileEvaluate    @   install.js:153
require @   install.js:82
meteorInstall.node_modules.pixi.js.src.core.sprites.webgl.SpriteRenderer.js @   SpriteRenderer.js:2
fileEvaluate    @   install.js:153
require @   install.js:82
meteorInstall.node_modules.pixi.js.src.core.index.js    @   index.js:28
fileEvaluate    @   install.js:153
require @   install.js:82
meteorInstall.node_modules.pixi.js.src.index.js @   index.js:4
fileEvaluate    @   install.js:153
require @   install.js:82
Mp.import   @   runtime.js:70
meteorInstall.client.main.jsx   @   main.jsx:1
fileEvaluate    @   install.js:153
require @   install.js:82
(anonymous function)    @   app.js?hash=acf17d5…:42
```

What is the correct way to import it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure how you've installed your pixi package, but here are few options to get it working:

**1) Via the [npm pixi package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pixi) (older now deprecated version):**

a) Install it: `meteor npm install --save pixi`

b) Reference it as:

```
import pixi from 'pixi';
console.log(pixi);
```

**2) Including a copy of the `pixi.js` file with your app (approach to use with the newest version of pixi):**

a) Download a copy of the [`pixi.js` file located on their github releases page](https://github.com/pixijs/pixi.js/releases).

b) Store the `pixi.js` file in your apps `/client/compatibility` directory.

c) Reference it as:

```
console.log(PIXI);
```

Comment: indeed I was installing with meteor npm install --save pixi.js

Comment: I validated too quickly `npm install --save pixi` install a deprecated package.

Comment: Yes I have already managed to use Pixi with the second options. I have also add `import * as PIXI from "/client/compatibility/pixi.min.js";` otherwise my IDE complains about an unknown variable.

Answer (score 3):

Actually it should be `import * as PIXI from 'pixi.js';`

`pixi.js` just exports all the functions in the PIXI library directly.

Comment: Thanks. This helped!